# Calling async function from custom flatlist view

Tags: react-native, asynchronous, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to call an async function in a customer flatlist view, but I am get errors caused by using await in the custom flatlist view:

```
async _customFlatlistView(item){
    promise = await SomeFunction(); 

    promise2 = await SomeOtherFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`await` can only be used in `async` functions

```js
_customFlatlistView = async item => {
  promise = await SomeFunction()
  promise2 = await SomeOtherFunction()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `await` keyword can only be used in adding the `async` keyword to the method signature:

```
    async _customFlatlistView(item){
        promise = await SomeFunction(); 

        promise2 = await SomeOtherFunction();
    }
```